# How to convert string to System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.String]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a table Quotation store QuotationNumber of each user that do quote.
Now I want to get the QuotationNumber print out on my view.

This is what I query in my controller :

```
Quotation iq = new Quotation();

string test = (from i in Quotations
              where i.CustomerID == c.ID
              select i.QuotationNumber).ToString();
```

When I display the test, it is out put :

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.String]
```

Could anyone show me the solution please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
List<string> test = (from i in Quotations
              where i.CustomerID == c.ID
              select i.QuotationNumber).ToList();
```

and then iterate over all resullts:

```
foreach (string quotationNumber in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", quotationNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but it display nothing on my page.

Comment: Are you sure you have  i.CustomerID that equal to c.ID ?

Comment: @TwTw: Great, Now It is work well now. But it has a little bit problem, while the same ID of user do many quotes, it display all the list from database. How can we display only a quote that currently done?

Comment: Sorry , But I don't understand which quotes do you want to select?

Comment: @TwTw : Thanks TwTw, now it is work well while I wrote like this `List<string> test = (from i in Quotations orderby i.LastUpdated descending where i.CustomerID == c.ID select i.QuotationNumber).Take(1).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

You've got a *query* - you need to execute it. Calling `ToString()` doesn't help you. There may be multiple matching quotations, for example. If you know there will only be one, you can use:

```
var query = from i in Quotations
            where i.CustomerID == c.ID
            select i.QuotationNumber;
string quotationNumber = query.Single();
```

or

```
var query = from i in Quotations
            where i.CustomerID == c.ID
            select i.QuotationNumber;
string quotationNumber = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

The first will throw an exception of there are no results; the second will return null if there are no results. Both will throw an exception if there's more than one result. Another pair of options is `First` and `FirstOrDefault`, which work the same way except they tolerate multiple matches.

Or you could iterate over *all* the results:

```
foreach (string quotationNumber in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", quotationNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. but when I do this, it error : `Cannot implicit convert char to string`.

Comment: @titi: Sorry, you need to get rid of the `ToString()` bit as well... will update my answer.

Comment: @titi: Well we don't know what you're doing with it - but perhaps there was no matching quote found?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to rewrite the ToString method of Quotation